# Как grep(нуть) строку в файле с символами ESC

Tags: grep

В файле присутствуют данные, например

```
echo -e "new file - \e[91mhello\e[0m" > file
```

Пытаюсь грепнуть эту строку:

```
grep "new file - hello" file
```

Не грепается ... `less` выводит: `new file - ESC[91mhelloESC[0m`

Если пробовать так:

```
grep "new file - ESC[91mhelloESC[0m" file
```

Выдает:

```
grep: Непарная [ или [^
```

Как это грепнуть?

Comment: `new file - .*hello`, `new file - .....hello`, и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо! помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> grep: Непарная [ или [^
> ```

для непосредственного указания мета-символа типа `[` надо добавить перед ним обратный слэш: `\[`.

---

символ `escape` имеет шестнадцатиричный код `1b`:

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ ls -d --color tmp | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 30 6d 1b 5b 30 31  3b 33 34 6d 74 6d 70 1b  |.[0m.[01;34mtmp.|
00000010  5b 30 6d 0a                                       |[0m.|
00000014
```

по умолчанию программе *grep* нельзя передать совсем уж произвольный символ (в виде шестнадцатиричного/восьмиричного кода). надо либо сформировать этот символ с помощью какой-нибудь другой программы, либо использовать опцию `-P`/`--perl-regexp` (если у вас реализация программы от проекта *gnu*). несколько вариантов:

```
$ ls -d --color tmp | grep -o -P '^\x1b\[0m' | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 30 6d 0a                                    |.[0m.|
00000005
$ ls -d --color tmp | grep -o "^$(printf '\x1b')\[0m" | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 30 6d 0a                                    |.[0m.|
00000005
$ ls -d --color tmp | grep -o "^"$'\x1b'"\[0m" | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 30 6d 0a                                    |.[0m.|
00000005
```

Comment: если что, во всех приведённых вариантах должно работать и просто `\e` вместо кода...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я старался излагать про общий случай произвольного символа. вообще, конечно, варианты есть и другие. вот автору вопроса вполне и точка подошла.